# Add a command into vimrc

Tags: vim, command

I'd like to copy something that I selected with VISUAL mode to X clipboard using xclip. How can I create a mapping in my vimrc that uses the selected text?

The command that I'd like to execute is the following:

```
xclip -selection c {selected text}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
vnoremap <F2> :w !xclip -selection c<CR><ESC>
```

Comment: Great! It works good but why when I use it Vim prints the command and says: "Press enter or type command to continue"?

Comment: I tried adding <silent> but Vim still prints that message. Is it possible to disable it?